# Writting UI component tree using an interface

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm writting a UI component tree using a base interface (not a base *class*). For now it has not much code. The UI entry is an `UIConfig` object. For some reason, creating components yields a `VerifyError` when running (not building) the code, like with `UICollection`:

> VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of UICollection in gingerbreadui.UICollection.
>
> ⨽ at Main()
>
> ⨽ at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
>
> ⨽ at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
>
> ⨽ at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
>
> ⨽ at runtime::AppRunner/run()
>
> ⨽ at ADLAppEntry/run()
>
> ⨽ at global/runtime::ADLEntry()

`Component` is the base interface for UI components... When removing the `implements` clause, it looks like the error stop arising, which looks to be a bug.

**container.as**

`UICollection` defines some methods, but no constructor.

```
package gingerbreadui {
    import flash.display.Sprite

    public final class UICollection implements Component {
        public const children: Vector.<Component> = new <Component> [];
        public var width: Object
                 , height: Object
                 , direction: String = 'horizontal'
                 , itemMargin: Number = 0;

        private const _root: Sprite = new Sprite;
        private var _width: Number = 0
                  , _height: Number = 0;

        // ...
    }
}
```

**menu.as**

```
package gingerbreadui {
    import flash.display.Sprite

    public final class UIMenu {
        public const top: UICollection = new UICollection

        internal const _root: Sprite = new Sprite
        internal var _cfg: UIConfig

        public function UIMenu() {
            _root.addChild(top.sprite)
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

**config.as**

```
package gingerbreadui {
    import flash.display.Sprite

    public final class UIConfig {
        internal var _root: Sprite;

        static public function fromSprite
            (root: Sprite) : UIConfig
        {
            var cfg: UIConfig = new UIConfig
            cfg._root = root
            return cfg
        }

        public function createMenu() : UIMenu {
            var menu: UIMenu = new UIMenu
            menu._cfg = this
            return menu
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess: **width** and **height** are getter/setter properties defined in **DisplayObject** or later. This kind of errors can be figured out by commenting everything then uncommenting one by one to catch the troublesome one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did a mistake when implementing an interface, however the compiler did not warn, and thus I silentily met this VerifyError at runtime.

The interface has a getter, but my class defined a regular method.